# Why are spurious SAX warnings appearing in my compilation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sax

I have a modest-sized multi-project solution written in C# which I am developing using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP. In the last few days it has taken to reporting scores of warnings like the following:-

> At least one of the arguments for 'ISAXXMLReader.getBaseURL' cannot be
>   marshaled by the runtime marshaler.  Such arguments will therefore be
>   passed as a pointer and may require unsafe code to manipulate.

Similar warnings are produced for `ISAXLocator`, `ISAXAttributes`, `ISAXXMLFilter`, and other apparently SAX related classes. I'm not using XML at all anywhere in the project.

While this isn't a crippling problem, genuine warnings are getting lost in the noise.

Does anyone know what the problem is, and what I can do about it?